# InheritedWidget and Navigation

Tags: flutter

I try to use inheritedWidget with my navigation.
when I do :

```
 Navigator.push(
        context,
        
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>CurrentUser(
                             user:state.currentUser,
                             child:BookSelection()),

            ));
  }
```

But when I am in BookSelection and I go in another MaterialPageRoute where I need currentUser, my CurrentUser.of(context).user is null.
I understand that I'm not in the same context, but is there a solution to have CurrentUser in all MaterialPageRoute under bookSelection tree ? Or do I have to copy for every MaterialPage the code above to have currentUser ?
May be it's not clear.
I have a Page A, B, C who need currentUser object. So my idea was to create an InheritedWidget with the currentUser.
I write the code to go from A to B. But when I go from B to C, in C currentUser is null. Do I have to create again an InheritedWidget at each new Page ?
Thanks.

Comment: You want to send the user object to the next screen right?

Comment: Yes. Not only the next one, but all screen below the next screen ( via navigation)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, this is how i usually do it:

- When you create a screen add a constructor that requires a user object to be provided

  ```
  class TabScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    static const screenID = 'tab_screen';
    static bool showSpinner = false;
    TabScreen({this.user});
    final User user;

  @override
  _TabScreenState createState() => _TabScreenState();
  }
  ```
- On the first screen get the user

  ```
  User loggedInUser;

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
  ```
- When you redirect to the screen that needs the user you can do this

  ```
   return Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
          pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => TabScreen(user: loggedInUser),
        ),
      );
  ```

After this TabScreen will have the user object available.

Comment: Thanks but with this solution, you have to pass for all screen your user object. When you use InheritedWidget, you don't have to pass for all screen. But my question is when you go to screen A to screenB with navigation, you lost the inheritedWidget value. I saw just one solution is to create each time a new InheritedWidget when I want to go to screen B to screen C. And I think it's weird and may be there's a better solution

Comment: I see, You can use the provider package and access the usar from just one place